# MySQL Select generating new columns

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | event    | seconds | date                |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  5 | open     |      0  | 2014-10-20 16:00:00 |
|  5 | assign   |      5  | 2014-10-20 16:00:05 |
|  5 | complete |     10  | 2014-10-20 16:00:15 |
|  5 | close    |     22  | 2014-10-20 16:00:37 |
|  6 | open     |      0  | 2014-10-20 17:00:00 |
|  6 | assign   |      7  | 2014-10-20 17:00:07 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Is there a select statement to return this without writing program logic?

```
+----+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id | open     | assign  | complete  | close   |
+----+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
|  5 |    0     |    5    |    10     |   22    |
|  6 |    0     |    7    |           |         |
+----+----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Yes it is called a pivot.

Comment: I was so close with my own logic... just didn't include the SUM :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
SUM(CASE WHEN event='open' THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as open,
SUM(CASE WHEN event='assign' THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as assign,
SUM(CASE WHEN event='complete' THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as complete,
SUM(CASE WHEN event='close' THEN seconds ELSE 0 END) as close
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

I assumed you need a sum of seconds for each id,it could be max ,min, etc.

Comment: @Radar Almost, but who`s counting.

Answer (score 2):

This is converting rows into columns, we can do CASE based aggregation

[`SQL Fiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/706441/4)

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX( case when event ='open' then seconds end ) as open,
       MAX( case when event ='assign' then seconds end ) as assign,
       MAX( case when event ='complete' then seconds end ) as complete,
       MAX( case when event ='close' then seconds end ) as close
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
```